# What does it mean "being deferred to by"?

Tags: meaning

What does it mean "being deferred to by" in the following sentence:

> An officer **being deferred to by** noncoms and enlisted men.

This is from [*The Bone Tree*](http://ebookhunter.ch/The%20Bone%20Tree:%20A%20Novel%20by%20Greg%20Iles_554b64ec66448907e67282fb/), Chapter 44.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. I hope you'll take some time to read our [*Details, Please...*](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) and [_So You Found a Sentence that Confused You..._](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source) meta posts, and provide a little bit more information in future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Voices in the dark.*
>
> One more powerful than the others . . . .   An officer being deferred to by noncoms and enlisted men.

Your example is an extended noun phrase.   "An officer" is modified by the passive participial phrase "being deferred to by noncoms and enlisted men".

In the active voice and cast as an independent clause in canonical order, "Noncoms and enlisted men are deferring to [this] officer."

In this context, the noncoms and enlisted men are allowing this officer to lead the action and give orders.   This is the manner in which his voice is more powerful than the others -- not necessarily louder, but worthy of attention and respect.   A voice to be obeyed.   A voice being obeyed.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to defer means to put off or postpone. To defer *to* someone is to "put off" your plans for the sake of theirs, e.g., "I think 'not guilty' is the best plea, but I'll defer to your opinion as a lawyer." Defer in your sentence likely means "show deference to," i.e., the men are respectfully submitting to the officer.

Comment: I think you might win the folk etymology badge.